# how to use Firebase in custom android SDK included in n number of android apps

Tags: android, firebase, sdk, kibana

I want to log events in my SDK and I was looking into Firebase for that but then I realized I need to pass the application package which I don't have as my SDK can be integrated into N number of apps. is it possible to use firebase inside SDK without application id? if yes please let me know how and if no please share alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

To fetch the application package you can simply get it at runtime:

```
getApplicationContext().getPackageName();
```

But I think you are asking for a different use case, you may want to check this documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/multiprojects#use_multiple_projects_in_your_application

That way you can basically make an instance of firebase completely apart from any other firebase instance that may exist, and you can pass in any parameter you may want.

Sorry if I misunderstood you.

Comment: Yes basically we need to make an instance of firebase independent of the app on which my sdk is integrated.